# Count how many days it will take using the while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

> A person has collected N amount of bags in the forest. One bag he
>   carried back home. On the second day he invited a friend and carried 2
>   bags home, on the third day each of them invited another friend and
>   carried 4 bags home and so on... Calculate how many days it will take
>   for all the bags to be carried back home. On the last day not all
>   friends have to have a bag.

I have no idea where to start, except that I should start with while (N>0)

```
while (N>0) {
    // have no idea where to start
}
```

So far I've come up with this:

```
while (n>0) {
    n=n-1;
    if (n!=0) {
       sum++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Start with pencil and paper to solve the problem. If you have that, translate it into code.

Comment: Agreed with @πάνταῥεῖ. First solve the math problem on paper then code it.

Comment: i have edited the post with what i think kind of works, however im not certain.

Comment: Start with brute force so that have something, then do a bit of math research. There are mathematical shortcuts that can reduce a summation sequence into one-line operations. You can probably take advantage of one to eliminate the loop.

Comment: The best way to prove that an algorithm works is to test it. Build a table of inputs and expected outputs. Run the inputs through the algorithm. If you don't get the expected outputs, you're found a bug in either your algorithm or your expectations. Either one needs to be fixed.

Comment: You’re counting how long it would take for one person to do the work alone. You also need to account for the daily doubling.

Comment: Just think that everyday the amount of bags coming home will be x2 than last day.

Comment: Are you having problems with the math part or the coding part?

Comment: @FeiXiang the coding part, i don't know how to put 1*n in to code, and for n to increase as the loop finishes 1 cycle.

Comment: im missing something here and i cant seem to find it, cant grasp the beginning of the code, either way it's too late for my brain to function, or i just dont understand the concept of the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize in advance, for I'm still actively learning C++, but think I can reproduce your desired output in PHP while loops. From what I could gather, the formula you would need is **n = n - i** with **i** being the iterator that doubles each day and **n** being the number of bags...

```
  $n = 10; // number of bags gathered
  $i = 1; // iterator for day 1
  $days = array($n); // create an array to help keep track of the days
  $n = $n - $i; // day 1 has to be done outside the loop
  array_unshift($days, $n); // prepend new n value to array

  // while loop
  while ($n > 0) {
    $i = ($i * 2); // double the iterator each day (run)
    $n = $n - $i;
    if ($n > 0) {
      array_unshift($days, $n); // prepend each new n value to array
    }
  }
  // count each item in the array
  echo $numberOfDays = count($days); // outputs 4
```

Checked it on pen and paper a few times with some small numbers and each turned out correct. I'm assuming this same concept could be applied to C++.

Comment: 1) Why `days` is an array? 2) `echo count($days);` is enough. 3) `day 1 has to be done outside the loop` Why?

Comment: 1) I put days as an array to count the amount of times the variable 'n' changes before it reaches 0. 2) I realized that, but it's also nice to store it for later + I was trying to be descriptive. 3) I guess it doesn't have to be done outside of the loop, maybe if I played around a little more I could have found an if statement that would allow it to be run inside the loop, but honestly it was the first working answer I could produce.

Answer (score 0):

You can't code if you don't first solve the problem logically. In your case the key to the solution is to remember that each day the amount of bags coming home will be double than last day. So here's the simplest solution I can think:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

   int N, days = 0;

   std::cin >> N;

   for ( int i = 1; N > 0; N -= i, i *= 2, ++days );

   std::cout << days;

   return 0;
}
```

So, `for` here does exactly what the problem says. Start first day with `N` bags and `i` friends. Each day (iteration) bring back `i` bags and then double the friends until all bags are home (`N` > 0).

Comment: problem is, i have to use the <while> loop, not the <for> loop. :/

Comment: You should be able to convert `for` into `while`.